# Decoding a string of letters

Tags: decode, decoding

Anyone knows how to decode this string;

```
RnJpbnRvIGlzIGEgZGlydHkgZnVycnkgezU2MTg0NDIyMTk3fQ
```

I've been browsing Google for half an hour trying to understand which format the above string is in but cannot reach a solution, so I can read up on how I decode it myself.

Answer (score 1):

That is Base64.
https://www.base64decode.org/

The text says

> Frinto is a dirty furry {56184422197}